# Possible memory leak in site with AJAX calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, performance, memory-leaks

I'm using a function in my site that makes an AJAX call. It returns back a JSON string wrapped in a javascript function while using JSONP to reach across domains to grab the data I need. The JSON string is very large, about 1MB in size. The problem I have is that I notice with each call my memory goes up about 1MB in size. What happens is that overtime, in IE9, I get an error stating that it's 'Out Of Memory'. How do I prevent this from happening?

[Here is a picture of the memory usage over time that I took with Chrome using the Memory Timeline.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVtxN.jpg)

I'm curious if that with each callback function of JSON data I receive, if it is stacking within the DOM, instead of having it get replaced entirely? Is there a way to make sure that I remove the old callback function JSON data from the DOM first, and then make the call to the API to get a new callback function filled with JSON data?

I launch the function with the following command from within my HTML:

```
setTimeout(grabParature, 10000);
```

Here is the function that is called (token is omitted for obvious reasons):

```
function grabParature() {
var url = "https://s3.parature.com/api/v1/5406/5426/Ticket";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: true,
    jsonp : "_callback_=",
    jsonpCallback: "theData",
    data: {
        "_status_type_": "open",
        "_pageSize_" : "500",
        "_output_" : "javascript",
        "_token_" : "#####################"
    },
    success: function (results) {
        var openTickets = 0;
        var newTickets = 0;
        var atschoolTickets = 0;
        var hardwareTickets = 0;
        var softwareTickets = 0;
        var networkTickets = 0;

        console.log(results);

        for(var i = 0; i < results.Entities.Ticket.length; i++)
        {
            var queue = "";
            var status = results.Entities.Ticket[i].Ticket_Status.Status.Name["#text"];

            if (results.Entities.Ticket[i].Ticket_Queue != undefined) {
                queue = results.Entities.Ticket[i].Ticket_Queue.Queue.Name["#text"];
            }

            if (status === "Open") {
                openTickets++;
            }
            else if (status === "New") {
                newTickets++;
            }

            if (queue === "Hardware") {
                hardwaretickets++;
            }
            else if (queue === "Atschool") {
                atschoolTickets++;
            }
            else if (queue === "Network") {
                networkTickets++;
            }
            else if (queue === "Software") {
                softwareTickets++;
            }
        }
        $('#span_openTickets').html(openTickets);
        $('#span_newTickets').html(newTickets);
        $('#span_hardwareTickets').html(hardwareTickets);
        $('#span_atschoolTickets').html(atschoolTickets);
        $('#span_networkTickets').html(networkTickets);
        $('#span_softwareTickets').html(softwareTickets);

        results = null;
    }
});

};
```

Comment: There is some info in here that might help: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/memory-leaks-with-ajax-calls

Comment: Are you running this multiple times with the `setTimeout()`?

Comment: ...and what version of jQuery are you running?

Comment: I am running this multiple time with setTimeout(). My version of jQuery is 1.10.2.

Comment: http://lbrandy.com/assets/jpg_vs_png2.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I removed the following line from my function:

```
console.log(results);
```

Now the website isn't consuming memory like it did in the posted picture. The memory timeline has more of a sawtooth graph as expected.